# Unexpected behaviour of types in c#, cannot recast to a struct

Tags: c#, dictionary, struct

Have quite a large code base that I am trying to get to grips with here. Once of the issues appears that the data object that I am trying to get at is a struct with a number of parameters, i.e. of the form:

```
public struct MyData
{
    public float A;
    public float B;
}
```

There is a collection of these types, however when I drill into each and every one of those entries into the collection which should have one of these types, I find that whilst I am looking at the underlying struct above, I cannot use the "dot form", say object.A to get at the value. When I try and cast as the struct I get an issue as the object that I am pointing says it is a different type, however when looking at it is the correct format. I think it may be something to do with being defined as a collection

```
var outputData = new myCollection<Tstuff>();
```

Here is the cast statement.

```
var myCast = (MyData) MyObject.Value;
```

and I get an issue I cannot convert type to Tstuff to MyData. Its off because hovering over MyObject, says it is of type KeyValuePair.

However when debugging, oddly the Immediate window in Visual Studio allows me to do this and for example I can then do the following:

```
myCast.A
```

and return the float in question. The two questions are:

1) Why cannot I do the cast when the object.Value is clearly of the correct type - ascertained when I use the .GetType()

2) Why can I do the cast in the immediate window of Visual Studio but not in the main body of the code.

Thanks in advance. Sorry its hard to post. This is a massive code set that I'm just getting involved with.

Here is some of the additional parts of the puzzle:

```
 var outputData = new myCollection<Tstuff>();
```

Looking at the definition for myCollection, we get the following:

```
public class myCollection<Tstuff> : BaseTransferValueCollection<string, Key, Tstuff>
    {
        public myCollection();
    }
```

if we drill down into that inherited class:

```
public abstract class BaseTransferValueCollection<TP, TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TP, IList<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>>
{


}
```

Here is the add process:

```
 dResults.Add(new KeyValuePair<Key, MyData>(
                                    new Key(kvpS.Key, id),
                                    new MyData
                                    {
                                        A = 100.00,
                                        B = 200.00,    
                                    }));
```

Sorry its not easy tracking stuff down in the code. So to summarize:

MyObject looks like the following, when we hover over it:

```
{[ida:765687645, idb:463786843, xxx.xxx.xxx.MyData]}
```

Comment: Can you make use of a where clause with Tstuff so that you enforce the rule that all Tstuff entries will implement some interface that allows you to get a MyData value?

Comment: @Ted, could you please expand?

Comment: If you can't change anything to add constraints, then try first turning it into object: var myCast = (MyData) (object)MyObject.Value;  This is very dicey code, however, and will break if you ever use something other than MyData with this generic collection.

Comment: @Ted. I tried this - it works. But I don't know why. I suspect its slow. But at least now I have access to the properties that I didn't before.

Comment: If you prefer to go the interface route, have MyData implement an interface like IMyData and set up A and B to have property getters/setters that are defined on the interface.  Then you might be able to use a where clause like public class myCollection<Tstuff>... where Tstuff : IMyData.  But if you have no control over MyData or the collection definitions, that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myCast = ((MyData) MyObject).Value;
```

Explanation:  an extra set of parens to indicate that you are casting MyObject as MyData, and then accessing the .Value member.  Otherwise, you are trying to cast MyObject.Value as a MyData.

**Edit**

I re-read your post.  This might not quite be the answer.  Can you post a little more code -- can you include the definition of the dictionary object, some code that adds your struct to the dictionary, and the code that is trying to pull it out of the dictionary?

Comment: Sadly this does not work. I'll look now to get more of the code. I'm struggling with the sheer size of the code base and the very nested data structures.

Answer (score 0):

C# uses a single typecasting syntax `(Foo)bar` to represent a number of different operations.  Among them:

- Compiler-generated conversions among certain types using primitive instructions [e.g. `(double)12.3f` will generate a "convert float to double" instruction].
- Invocation of any conversion-operator functions defined in the source or destination type
- Reinterpreting a reference as a different type it is already known to be (e.g. casting a value of type `String` to a value of type `Object`)
- Ensuring that a particular value of one reference type is also a value of another reference type, and either reinterpreting it as the latter type or throwing an exception.
- Taking a value and, if it isn't already a heap reference, producing a new heap object containing that value and returning a reference to that.
- Taking a heap reference, ensuring that it identifies an object of specified type, and returning either the reference or the contents of the object identified thereby, depending upon what the specified type requires.

There is no single "convert type X to type Y" operation that the compiler can use for any arbitrary types X and Y.  The compiler must be able to identify which of the above conversions is required to generate the correct code.  Note that the compiler can handle all conversions to `Object` using the fifth method, and all conversions from `Object` using the sixth, so adding an intermediate cast to object will allow code to compile even if the compiler doesn't know the types in question.  Note also, however, that successful compilation does not imply successful or efficient execution.  An attempt to use the fifth and sixth methods together will always compile, but it will fail at runtime if in fact one of the first two methods was required.

It would be helpful if there were some way via which code could say:

```
 // Hypothetical syntax: "converts var x = y as z" tries to convert y to type z
 // and if it works, defines label x to the result

if (converts var temp = myThing as System.Drawing.Point)
{
   temp.X = 4;
}
else
{
   // Can't do conversion
}
```

The .NET Just-In-Time compiler's generics-handling mechanisms, however, could not handle such constructs if a generically-typed `myThing` could be a value type; if e.g. `myThing` was an `int`, it would have to generate code that looked like:

```
if (typeof(Int32) == typeof(System.Drawing.Point))
{
  System.Drawing.Point temp = myThing; // Illegal
}
```

Even though the code would never in fact execute and it thus wouldn't matter what code, if any, the JIT generated for the assignment, there's no mechanism via which the JITter could simply omit the impossible assignment statement.  It would have to generate a workable assignment and, failing to do so, would have to reject the construct entirely.